# Doctrine 2 WHERE IN - invalid input syntax for integer: "Array"

Tags: doctrine-orm, where-clause

I am trying to get user accounts for specific users.

BASIC CODE:

```
$ownerIds = array();
foreach ($owners as $owner) {
    $ownerIds[] = $owner->getId();
}
    $qb = $this->entityManager
    ->createQueryBuilder();
```

THEN I tried following:

1.

```
$qb->select('a')
    ->from('Account', 'a')
    ->andWhere('a.owner IN (?1)')
    ->setParameters(array(
        1 => $ownerIds
    );
```

2.

```
$qb->select('a')
        ->from('Account', 'a')
        ->add('where', $qb->expr()->in('a.owner', '?1'))
        ->setParameters(array(
            1 => $ownerIds
        );
```

I also tried to switch question mark with parameter name ':name'

```
$qb->select('a')
        ->from('Account', 'a')
        ->add('where', $qb->expr()->in('a.owner', ':name'))
        ->setParameters(array(
            ':name' => $ownerIds
        );
```

But I am still getting this error: **Invalid input syntax for integer: "Array"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$qb->select('a')
   ->from('Account', 'a')
   ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('a.owner', $ownerIds));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: OK. This works fine. But why I can not pass parameter like usually?